# Destroy nil value in Active Record collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model and it is called `Scripts` It `has_many => Pages` Therefore, `Page belongs_to => Scipts`

I deleted a page object and now when running `Script.pages` the first value is `nil` (Luckily it's the first value, because if not, I'd have no other way of referencing it because it has no ID)

I need to `destroy` the `nil` value because it's breaking my app by being `nil` However, running `Script.pages.first.destroy` returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

Which makes sense. Right now, I need to know how to get this corrupted data out of my collection of pages.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can't destroy something that's not there. If you need this to be not `nil` then you need to make a page so that `first` returns a useful object. You need to *undestroy* it.

Comment: How you end up having nils on pages call?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go [Array.compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-compact):

```
Script.pages.compact.first.destroy
```

You can also try to reload your collection with [ActiveRecord::Relation.reload](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/reload):

```
Script.pages.reload.first.destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any pages. `0 == script.pages.count` will return `true`. The `.first` method returns a `nil` on an empty array. `assert [].first.nil?` will pass.

Comment: So I do have `Script.pages` does have pages. However, in that collection of pages, there is a nil object.

Comment: What does `p script.pages.map(&:nil?)` print out?

Comment: Good question! It returns what I expected:

`=> [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]`

The first object is `nil`, the rest are not

Comment: ActiveRecord is not supposed to do that. Can you read `SELECT` statements in your `log/test.log`, and find the one that populates that `.pages` member? If you run that `SELECT` statement alone in your database console what does it return?